# How to prevent Vue to interpreted custom tags?

Tags: vue.js

I have got Vue App. But I need to to add to it some custom tags, that come from another JS framework. How to prevent Vue to try to interpreted it?

```
<slider floor="100" ceiling="1000" step="1" ></slider>
```

Now I am getting error:
`Unknown custom element: <slider> - did you register the component correctly?`

Comment: To get possible answers submitted it helps to include pertinent code from your app.  Where did you import/register the component?

Answer (score 5):

If you are using Vue Version 2.0

You can use config's ignoredElements

```
Vue.config.ignoredElements = ['slider']
```

It is already implemented in Vue 2.0, and will be implemented in Vue 1.1

resource: [vuejs issues 3090: Ignore some custom HTML components](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/3090)

Answer (score 4):

This is a warning, not an error, so you should have no issues with it.  You can use `Vue.config.silent = true` to hide all of the warnings. Also I think it would be hidden if you set `Vue.config.debug = false`.  So it is really just a logged warning during development but shouldn't affect production.