# How tell in vue js that a component is not a custom one (<menuitem>)

Tags: javascript, menuitem, vue.js

I use `vue.js` and it recognize a component (`menuitem`) as a custom one.

```
 <menu type="context" id="viewerContextMenu">
    <menuitem id="firstId"></menuitem>
    <menuitem id="secondId"></menuitem>
    <menuitem id="thidId"></menuitem>
</menu>
```

So, I have the warning in my browser console:

```
"Unknown custom element: <menuitem> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option."
```

The thing is, `menuitem` is not a custom component. See: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_menuitem.asp

How can I tell `vue.js` that:

- either menuitem is not a custom component
- or don't check this part of code.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: An answer to a similar question indicates that it may not be possible to do what you want, unless you hide all warnings: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34810206/how-to-prevent-vue-to-interpreted-custom-tags

Comment: W3schools is a terrible source of information, much information you will find there is plain wrong

Comment: In the same link you shared, it is also pointed that this element is supported in only 1 browser

Comment: You may have solved this already but just out of curiosity, can you show how you registered the component in the first place?

Comment: @AntónioQuadrado Unfortunatly, we have apply another solution : develop our own Vue.js component. This is because "menuitem" is not supported by FF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing it's that menuitem it's not supported by all browsers, check compatibility 
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Element/menuitem

Vue.js recognize it as a custom element since **browser** itself doesn't recognize it.

If it's not completely necessary, change the element to a more stable html item :).

Hope it helps, and happy coding.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Indeed, "menuitem" is not supported by firefox. Finally, we switch off this part of code and developp our own vue.js component. It's much easier this way...

Answer (score 4):

You can set "ignored elements" through `Vue.config.ignoredElements`.

```
Vue.config.ignoredElements = [
  'menuitem'
]
```

Comment: More information in the Vue docs: https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#ignoredElements